# VLC is unable to play mpd file: main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, mpeg-dash, mp4box

I tried to implement HTTP adaptive stream over mininet. I have converted the video file into five different quality versions. MP4BOX generates the video files successfully. However, when I try to request the mpd file with vlc only audio plays with no video. Please could you tell me what is the problem?
Please visit this link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rSeuf1J1UNOoOxTJI_T4WTLfRG3p8ZGF/view?usp=sharing  which contains the mpd file and video segments (.m4s)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivpSD.png)

Comment: This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465734

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The audio works fine but video is not playing. I have looked at the mpd file generated by the MP4Box, if I delete the timescale attribute the video plays fine but I am not quite sure that would've solved the issue.  I have also installed smplayer, to try out different players, and seems that the mpd file works fine, however, I am a bit confused whether the smplayer is able to paly dash with all the adaptations. The main problem is why VLC is showing buffer deadlock prevented?

Comment: main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented is NOT an error

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example sharing _pictures_ of logs is really not good practice

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rSeuf1J1UNOoOxTJI_T4WTLfRG3p8ZGF/view?usp=sharing

The link contains the audio and video dashed files, mpd file and many segments of the video (.m4s).

when i try to open the mpd file with vlc, only audio is playing with no video. 
i have provided the screenshot as it showed main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented which i do not understand.